# Drawing Triangles with PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a `QGraphicsScene`, one which I'm trying to add a triangle via a `QGraphicsPolygonItem`.

```
class MainScene(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene):
def __init__(self, *args, parent=None):
    self.brush = QtGui.QBrush('94c3e4')
    QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene.__init__(self, parent, *args)
    self.setBackgroundBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor.fromRgb(209, 233, 249)))
....
## run every time a point is selected to become part of a triangle
    TrianglePts.append(Points2[indexW].scenePos())
    Points2[indexW].greenSelect()
    if len(TrianglePts) == 3:
        print(TrianglePts)
        triangle = TriangleItem(QtGui.QPolygonF(TrianglePts))
        self.addItem(triangle)


class TriangleItem(QtWidgets.QGraphicsPolygonItem):
    def __init__(self, polygon, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QGraphicsPolygonItem.__init__(self, polygon, parent)
        self.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor.fromRgb(249, 245, 209)))
```

For some reason, the triangle is never rendered. I do something similar to render points, and it seems to work. Here's the custom class for that:

```
class VertexItem(QtWidgets.QGraphicsEllipseItem):
def __init__(self, x, y, parent=None):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    QtWidgets.QGraphicsEllipseItem.__init__(self,parent)
    self.setRect(x, y, 20, 20)
    #self.setFlags(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
    #self.setFlags(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
    #self.setFlags(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
    self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)
```

Does anyone know what I need to do to get the triangles to render? I'm happy to provide any more necessary code.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer. Turns out the points I was sending to my TriangleItem were null - to fix it, I replaced

```
TrianglePts.append(Points2[indexW].scenePos())
```

with

```
TrianglePts.append(QtCore.QPointF(Points2[indexW].x + 10, Points2[indexW].y + 10))
```